# Program writes out chars as ascii codes, but only sometimes

Tags: c#

I was bored so I decided to create a little rock paper scissors game. It isn't complete because I only wanted to include necessary code. It looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        char[] enemyznak = new char[9];
        char[] znak = enemyznak;
        char input;
        Console.WriteLine("A as in pAper, D as in Diorite, S as in Scissors");
        Random random = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            Input:
            input = Console.ReadLine()[0];
            switch (input)
            {
                case 'A': znak = Paper(znak);
                    break;
                case 'D': znak = Rock(znak);
                    break;
                case 'S': znak = Scissors(znak);
                    break;
                default: Console.WriteLine("Unknown Character"); goto Input;
            }

            switch (random.Next(0,3))
            {
                case 0: enemyznak = Paper(enemyznak);
                    break;
                case 1: enemyznak = Rock(enemyznak);
                    break;
                case 2: enemyznak = Scissors(enemyznak);
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(znak[0] + znak[1] + znak[2] + "         " + enemyznak[0] + enemyznak[1] + enemyznak[2]);
            Console.WriteLine(znak[3] + znak[4] + znak[5] + "         " + enemyznak[3] + enemyznak[4] + enemyznak[5]);
            Console.WriteLine(znak[6] + znak[7] + znak[8] + "         " + enemyznak[6] + enemyznak[7] + enemyznak[8]);

        }

    }

    static char[] Rock(char[] znak)
    {
    // just like Scissors except different characters
    }
    static char[] Scissors(char[] znak)
    {

        znak[0] = 'o';
        znak[1] = ' ';
        znak[2] = '/';
        znak[3] = ' ';
        znak[4] = '¤';
        znak[5] = ' ';
        znak[6] = 'o';
        znak[7] = ' ';
        znak[8] = '\\';
        return znak;
    }
    static char[] Paper(char[] znak)
    {
    // just like Scissors except different characters
    }

}
```

During the printing out phase, it shows the player's symbol as weird numbers (such as 190 228 235 for Scissors). However, enemy symbol is written out as it should be, in characters. I tried comparing the segments but they seem the same to me, so what causes this inconsistency?

Comment: My guess is that the chars are added together with their numeric value and not string concatenated as you expect. Either call .ToString() on each char in the Console.WriteLine or return a string[]  from your Rock, Paper and Scissor methods.

Comment: Not the bug you're asking about, but when you initialise `char[] znak = enemyznak` that means `znak` and `enemyznak` are referencing the same array - so changes made to one will affect the other, and vice versa. That doesn't look intended; you should probably initialise `znak` like so: `char[] znak = new char[9];`

Comment: Changing every 'char' to 'string' and every apostrophe to quotation marks does solve the problem. I am still wondering why it happens though. Perhaps it's a bug in the compiler itself? @MatthewWatson , thanks for the idea, I was too lazy to write new char[9] again so I thought that, since it happens before anything is written inside the array, it just copies its length.

Comment: It's not a bug in anything but your code.

Comment: Then what should I change for both the symbols to be drawn and not become numbers?

Comment: *Perhaps it's a bug in the compiler itself?* - thing is, with a compiler used by millions of perple every day, it's quite likely it has very, very few bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bumped into C# operator priority and its implicit behavoiur.

To fully understand the behaviour, let us start from three things:

- what your code is actually calling
- how the `+` operator works
- what is `char` type

**1. What your code is actually calling**

Let us focus on the given line:

```
Console.WriteLine(znak[0] + znak[1] + znak[2] + "         " + enemyznak[0] + enemyznak[1] + enemyznak[2]);
```

Once you step in while debigging, you will see that the signature of this method is: `public static void WriteLine(string? value)`

**2. How the `+` operator works**

See documentation: [+ and += operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#string-concatenation)

In short:

> When one or both operands are of type string, the + operator concatenates the string

**3. What is `char` type**

See documentation: [char (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char#conversions)

In short:

> Moreover, for char operands, arithmetic and bitwise logical operators perform an operation on the corresponding character codes and produce the result of the int type.

**We can gather all those details to find out what is going on:**

1. We are calling  `Console.WriteLine(znak[0] + znak[1] + znak[2] + "         " + enemyznak[0] + enemyznak[1] + enemyznak[2]);` (so `WriteLine(string? value)`)
   2, Program to be able to call `WriteLine(string? value)` will create a variable of type `string?` with the following value: `znak[0] + znak[1] + znak[2] + "         " + enemyznak[0] + enemyznak[1] + enemyznak[2]`
2. As we now from 2, adding `char` and `char` with `+` operator will result in `int`:

   - znak[0]    111 'o' char
   - znak[1]    32 ' '  char
   - znak[2]    47 '/'  char
   - ...
3. so `znak[0] + znak[1]` = `143`, `143 + znak[2]` = `190` (`such as 190 228 235 for Scissors`)
4. Now as we now from 3 `When one or both operands are of type string, the + operator concatenates the string` so: `190 + "         "` = `"190" + "         "` = `"190         "`.
5. Now on the left hand side we have a `string`. So (as we know from 3) `"190         " + + enemyznak[0] + enemyznak[1] + enemyznak[2]` will result in `string`.

You can run the following experiment:

- add empty string at the very beginning:

```
Console.WriteLine("" + znak[0] + znak[1] + znak[2] + "         " + enemyznak[0] + enemyznak[1] + enemyznak[2]);
Console.WriteLine("" + znak[3] + znak[4] + znak[5] + "         " + enemyznak[3] + enemyznak[4] + enemyznak[5]);
Console.WriteLine("" + znak[6] + znak[7] + znak[8] + "         " + enemyznak[6] + enemyznak[7] + enemyznak[8]);
```

See what will happen. As you have `string` + `char`, it will result in `string`.

Comment: I thought of this yesterday when I went to sleep and I felt pretty dumb for not realisizing earlier. This explains it better than I understood it before though. Thanks for the answer!